# Is it possible to undo "Discard Changes" in Atom?

Tags: git, atom-editor

While working on my assignment, I saw that there 40 files in Unstaged changes in the Git part of atom. (in the panel on the right side) To remove them, I clicked individual files and selected "Discard All changes". Now I see that all the 40 files have been removed.

Although I recovered 12 files by "Undo Last discard", I need all the other files too. I want to recover those files, as they had all the code that I had written this full semester.

[image]

Note - I have not understood Git and GitHub properly even after some tutorials, so forgive me if I did something silly.

Comment: Have these files ever been staged before?

Comment: No, they haven't been staged before.

Comment: Vim has an option to save files to a backup directory, which can be a lifesaver. A little script that runs when a shell opens and scans that directory and purges files over n-days old will then keep it under control. Many other editors have similar functionality. I'd suggest searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Unstaged changes" is a complicated word to say "this is what I did, and have not put into git yet", and "discard them" means, unfortunately, "remove the stuff I did and haven't saved in git yet".

`git` will not help you there, you have to look at what your editor or your system provides to undelete files : check the trash can, your editor's options to view a history of files you saved locally ...

As a last resort you may use an file recover utility.